# Burninate [external-javascript-library]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I recently came across the tag [external-javascript-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external-javascript-library). It has <s>21</s> 11 question and 1 watcher with no tag wiki.

I feel like this tag does not add any useful information to the questions and an external resource can be defined differently. It can be an off-site resource to be included or a script outside a specific scope.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
Actually yes.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
Not necessarily, I voted to close some the question it currently is applied to.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
No

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
No, some questions deal with included/requiring external resource, some are just about the usage of external resources.

Comment: As far as I remember, less than 50 questions doesn't really require a full burnination request

Comment: Yes, I read that, but I wasn't sure if I could go ahead and just remove the tag from the remaining questions. Per wiki if the burniation tag "Please, do not start retagging before community consensus is reached", does that apply to the same condition or should I just retag my question here on Meta?

Comment: @empiric For the abbreviated procedure you need the support of at least one other person who has 20k+ reputation (e.g. a "Trusted User").

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you did good not rushing to retag. I think that an important thing when removing a tag (even with less than 50 questions) is to really go over the questions and clean-up. If a tag needs to go, there are good chances that it has a few off-topic questions that we can get rid of in the process

Comment: There's also an [external-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external-library) tag.

Comment: that made sense; since `internal-javascript-library` is non-exist

Comment: Getting rid of this tag sounds reasonable to me.